# Slide up animation using TransitionManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to achieve an animation like this using TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(). How should i go about it? The textView should be the same. I can't create a new textView when Text 1 goes up and fades out.

Currently i'm using a TextSwitcher but want to understand if there is a better solution out there using TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()

[image]

Comment: could you show me how to record your screen device and export to gif file?

Comment: It's a native screen recorder on samsung that i use. You can use AZ Screen Recorder or other such apps. For conversion to gif, i use https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif.